# How to pass input parameter to VBA http POST URL

Tags: vba, http, post, input

I am new to VBA . I am trying to get some input parameters from InputBox and I want to pass this InputBox element to my post request URL . but I don't know how should I pass the value to my URL?

for eg->
Dim iInput As String
iInput = InputBox("Please enter a number", "Create Invoice Number", "Enter your input text HERE")

**Url = "myurl.com/api/v4/projects/3765/ref/master/trigger/pipeline?token=123&variables[check1]=2"**
**objHTTP.Open "POST", Url, False**

here, Instead of 2(in the end) I need to pass this 2 through InputBox by taking userinput. how we should modify the current URL? please let me know.
thanks

Comment: Do you really mean POST, or GET?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yes it is POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate two strings with &

```
Url = "myurl.com/api/v4/projects/3765/ref/master/trigger/pipeline?token=123&variables[check1]=" & iInput
```

Comment: good to hear that! Maybe you could accept my answer please